# elasticsearch.jar package's version is not correct

Tags: maven, elasticsearch, pom.xml

when I user high level client of es,with use the dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

and the dependency is transitived at the elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-6.2.4.pom：

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
  <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
  <version>6.2.4</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

But! the maven downloaded the version of elasticsearch.jar is 2.6.4 not 6.2.4!!!
And When I build mvn dependency:tree,
the result is: "2.4.6"
what’ wrong!!!